# Is WML and WMLScript dead?

Tags: wml, wtai

**Is WML and WMLScripts are used anymore ?** I remember writing WML apps with classic-asp on server-side and we used interact with phone functionality from client using WMLScript and WTAI and do some cool things like, adding phone numbers to address book, trigger a call from WMLScript and much more. I still miss those things. I really want to know if modern web-browsers on phone have replaced WML with rich HTML support.

I also found that one of the most active [WML and WAP forum Openwave Developers](http://developer.openwave.com/) of our time is now discontinued which is no less than a shock to me. The forum also provided a nice WAP development SDK for testing WAP gateway simulation and WAP-pages on openwave browser simulator. All of these is now not seem to be available.

Answer (score 2):

BEFORE DOWN VOTING EXPLAIN WHY, IF IS JUST BECAUSE OF IGNORANCE THEN STAY AWAY.

It is not dead yet.

It is used by some POS systems such as POSWEB, I have been developing on it for years in conjunction to ASP.NET to generate dynamic WML cards or downloadable catalogs, receipts, etc.

[APPI Tecnologia's POSWEB Solution](http://www2.appi.com.br/ui/solucao/Default.aspx?Sol=454&lang=en-US)

Also another similar platforms do exist such as VERIWEB which are intended for the same purpose. Also I heard about similar ported WML/WMLScript being used in compact network enabled devices such as food / groceries dispensers, traveling card machines, etc.

This implementations supports mostly of the WML/WMLScript standard however it usually integrates additional functionality (depending on the target device), such as Smart Card processing, Simetric and assimetric cryptography, flat and indexed files creation and so on.

Answer (score 1):

WML is still alive and in use many modern browsers doses not supporting WML for example andoid browsers like Firefox, Chrome but Opera still support WML for mobile and for web browsers also. 
WML is more friendly to old phones but xHTML MP is the future in mobile WAP sites.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, it's becoming less and less common out there in the wild.

You might find the odd device coming through that only does WML, but the effort to support those few might not be your goal in which case starting at html should be OK.

The users of those older phones typically already accept that their phone isn't the best and can't do as much as other phones.

Answer (score 0):

Check out 0.facebook.com! There's been some resurgence of WML interest among some companies, mine included after Facebook Zero.  The idea is that much of the technology still used in the developing world utilizes old technologies like WML, and coding up modern pages in WML will increase access in the developing world.